# Adding Column Description to BigQuery schema definition

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to specify comments in the schema definition of a BigQuery table via the API?

I use the following schema when creating a BigQuery table via the Hadoop connector

```
[{"name" : "event_id", "type" : "integer"},{ "name" : "categorization" , "type" : "string" }]
```

And I want something like

```
[{"name" : "event_id", "type" : "integer", "description" : "The event identifier"},{ "name" : "categorization" , "type" : "string" }]
```

EDIT: I've just tried this with the spark connector but it doesn't work. The descriptions are still empty

```
BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryOutput(
      bqConfiguration, projectId, bqDatasetId, bqTable, schema)
    bqConfiguration.set(
      "mapreduce.job.outputformat.class",
      classOf[BigQueryOutputFormat[_,_]].getName)

    new JavaPairRDD(rdd.map((null, _))).saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(bqConfiguration)
  }
```

DOUBLE EDIT: Added some code for context

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what BigQuery provides you with
You can do this either upon table creation with [Tables: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert) API or you can add to existing table using [Tables: patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch) API
See respective parameters to be used in [Table Resources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource)
You can have description for whole table and for each field

Answer (score 0):

Yes, table fields can have their own descriptions.  The schema you posted with the description should work when sent to the API.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#schema.fields.description

Comment: Tried it with the Spark Connector, but doesn't work. My schema has descriptions but they don't show up in the column description.